# Combine real and planned data in PowerBI KPI visualizations

Tags: powerbi

I've got two primary datasets:

1. Real data with all sales transactions.

   For example `RealData`:

   ```
   Date;Sales
   16-01-2017;1200
   20-01-2017;1500
   05-02-2017;800
   08-02-2017;1100
   13-02-2017;300
   ```

   Etc.
2. A plan with total sales I want to achieve, with totals at the last day of each month.

   For example `EndOfMonthTargets`:

   ```
   Date;Sales
   31-01-2017;3000
   28-02-2017;2500
   ```

   Etc.

In my real data I (a) also have data from the years before 2017, and obviously I have the targets for each month in 2017. The RealData is always live / up to date.

What I'm trying to do is show KPI visualizations: how is the real data vs the plan doing. However, I can't figure out how to relate the two datasets, because the cannot really be joined together.

**What is the idiomatic way to do this in PowerBI?**

---

I've tried:

- adding a column to each source with its respective status (`"real"` vs `"plan"`)
- creating a union (i.e. "Append Queries as New")
- adding a column `Month = MONTH([Date])`

Giving me this data:

[image: sample unioned data]

But that's weird, because then the KPI visualization will include the "Plan" data either at the start or worse at the end where it will be plotted as the "current" number.

The expected output is a KPI visualization:

- showing the absolute number of sales summed by year (or month, if my slicers are set that way!)
- with the `Target goals` retrieved from the plan data
- with a trend based on previous years (not included in my sample data)

How do I achieve that?

Comment: It unclear to me, do you want to compare january 2017 total sales from real data with `31-01-2017` - 3000?. It would be useful if you include expected result.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta Your assumption is correct. I've tried to included the expected result in my last paragraph, will try to enhance my question a bit. But basically, yeah: if my slicer is set to "January" then I want my KPI to show that the actual number is 2700, and make it red showing it's -300 relative to the Plan to have 3000 at the end of January.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to join tables like this. What you have are 2 tables with different granularities: a sales table that goes to the day, and a target table that goes down to the month. It's a common request to model them against each other, and it boils down to having a lookup table that both fact tables can join with.

What I would recommend:

1. Have a table of your real data
2. Have a table of your plan/target data, using the last day of the month is fine
3. Do not relate these 2 fact tables together directly
4. Rather, have a separate date lookup table, to which both tables are joined. This date dimension should, at a minimum, have a month & year column (e.g. March 2017).
5. Join both fact tables to your date table
6. Hide the date fields in your 2 fact tables, so that you aren't tempted to use them in visuals (you have to use the date fields from the lookup table instead)

You can then create measures to SUM your actual and targets. And then additional measures that subtract those 2 measures against each other (or divide one into the other). All those measures will then be sliceable by the month & year on your date table. (You could slice them by date too, but because targets are assigned to the last day of the month, that granularity will be less than helpful.)

There's a lot of good information & examples here: http://www.daxpatterns.com/handling-different-granularities/

Comment: The other answers were helpful as well, and even though this answer is lacking some detail it *is* the route I took in my current solution. (Though I cheated and used a DAX lookup function instead of the lookup table from step 4. But I might go all out and use that after all in a later version.)

Comment: The crux of your problem was the join, so I admittedly focused my answer on that, rather than how to build the measures/KPI. I'm glad you got it working & thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

The way I would do it:

- Add a calculated column to both `real` and `targets` tables:
  `Month = Date(Actual[Date].[Year],Actual[Date].[MonthNo],1)`
  `Month = Date(Target[Date].[Year],Target[Date].[MonthNo],1)`
- Create relashionships between these
- Plot `SUM(RealData[Sales])` and `Target[Sales]` against `Target[Month]`

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate, perhaps add a screengrab or two how this would work in practice? I can not get this to work at all...

Comment: Apologies, reading back my comment seems a bit rude (wasn't intended to be so!). I do thank you for your suggestion, but I'm having a hard time using your answer to construct a real solution in my scenario. A few things that I struggle(d) with are that the `Month` formula didn't seem to work as is (needed `MonthDayOne = DATE(YEAR([Date]); MONTH([Date]); 1)` instead), that in the mean time I had added 2016 data that throws the solution off. Some more details in the answer would help a lot.

Comment: No worries. Sorry - I did get the formula a bit wrong. Should be fixed; hope screenshots help. Will be happy to help further, if this still doesn't work.

Comment: Thx, the edits help. I did need a KPI visualization (and part of my question/problem was how to configure that visual), but I see how your solution would also give proper insights. Your answer helped me understand my problem for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a measure to calculate the Actual total and measure to calculate the Planned by each month or end of month. Then create a measure to compare the difference between Planned total and Actual total.

```
Actual =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( RealDate[Sales] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( RealDate ),
        MONTH ( [Date] ) = MONTH ( MAX ( EndOfMonthTargets[Date] ) )
            && YEAR ( [Date] ) = YEAR ( MAX ( EndOfMonthTargets[Date] ) )
    )
)
```

```
Planned = SUM(EndOfMonthTargets[Sales])
```

```
ActualVSPlanned = [Actual] - [Planned]
```

Now use that measures and the Date in eEndOfMonthTargets table to build a matrix:

[image]

For the ActualVSPlanned measure use conditional formating as follows:

[image]

You will get something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerQuery to transform data.

"Real" table:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRecords({[Date="16.01.2017", Sales = 1200], [Date="20.01.2017", Sales=1500], [Date="05.02.2017", Sales = 800], [Date="08.02.2017", Sales = 1100], [Date="13.02.2017", Sales = 300], [Date="10.01.2016", Sales = 1400], [Date="02.02.2016", Sales = 1800]}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"Sales", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

"Plan" table:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRecords({[Date="31.01.2017", Sales = 3000], [Date="28.02.2017", Sales=2500], [Date="31.01.2016", Sales = 2800], [Date="29.02.2016", Sales = 2700]}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"Sales", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Your query for getting data, let's name it GetData:

```
let
    t1 = Table.AddColumn(Real, "Source", each "Real"),
    t2 = Table.AddColumn(Plan, "Source", each "Plan"),
    MergedTable = Table.Combine({t1, t2}),
    AddYear = Table.AddColumn(MergedTable, "Year", each Date.Year([Date])),
    AddMonth = Table.AddColumn(AddYear, "Month", each Date.Month([Date])),
    Group = Table.Group(AddMonth, {"Year", "Month", "Source"}, {{"Sales", each List.Sum([Sales]), type number}})

in
    Group
```

You may avoid using last step by grouping results at report level, but this will result in users being able to view amount of each sale. If this is expected behavior, just remove `Group` step, or replace it with `Table.RemoveColumn` to remove [Date].

If you need ***separate columns*** for Plan and Real values, then pivot *Source* column.

Then just use GetData query in clustered column chart.